# Putting html inside form label wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label, form-for

I'm using html_safe method in my label in order to put a link inside that label, but It wont work

**This**

```
Acepto los <%= f.label ("#{link_to 'Terminos y condiciones', terms_path}").html_safe, class: "inline" %>
```

**Prints this**

```
 Acepto los <a href="/terms">terminos y condiciones</a>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with a block; also I think in your case a `label_tag` might be better?

```
<%= label_tag class: "inline" do %> 
  <%= link_to 'Terminos y condiciones', terms_path %>
<% end %>
```

- http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label
- http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/label_tag